# Linux system hangs after unlocking encrypted boot disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, encryption

I've Libreboot a Thinkpad X60 with installed Parabola Linux on it and LUKS encrypted disk, everything was working.

A month ago I decided to upgrade it, so I switched to SSD (Goodram IRDM gen. 2 SSD), again installed Parabola, and made same setup as earlier, also with encryption.

But after the disk upgrade, when I try to boot, after it ask me for passphrase for disk, instead displaying LightDM, laptop hangs up and I must restart it.

Only one of (on average) three attempts is successful and I can login to working system. I thought that is software problem, so I reinstalled Parabola Linux, this time with Linux-libre LTS kernel instead of default Linux-libre, but it did not change anything.

Comment: Perhaps the SSD needs a firmware update.

Comment: There is no firmware update for that model on producer site. I've Goodram IRDM gen. 2 SSD

Comment: I can upload boot logs if that will help

Answer (score 1):

After change to SSD, Thinkpad was booting too fast, so lightdm was loaded before graphics. To fix that I must write `logind-check-graphical=true` in lightdm config.